# Linear interpolation Matlab to C++

Tags: c++, image, matlab, signal-processing

I don't have a strong mathematics/Matlab background. I would like to convert this Black level correction function from Matlab to C++. Please comment about on the code style and correctness of my equation.

**Matlab**

```
   function output = calculateBlackLevel(blStruct, AG, ET)
    blLut = zeros(length(blStruct), size(blStruct{1}.black_level,2));
    etLut = zeros(length(blStruct), 1);

    for k = 1 : length(blStruct)
        bl = blStruct{k};

        if length(bl.analog_gain) == 1
            blLut(k, :) = bl.black_level;
        elseif AG > max(bl.analog_gain) || AG < min(bl.analog_gain)
            blLut(k, :) = interp1(bl.analog_gain, bl.black_level, AG, 'nearest', 'extrap');
        else
            blLut(k, :) = interp1(bl.analog_gain, bl.black_level, AG);
        end

        etLut(k) = bl.exposure_time;
    end

    if length(etLut) == 1
        output = blLut;
    elseif ET > max(etLut) || ET < min(etLut)
        output = interp1(etLut, blLut, ET, 'nearest', 'extrap');
    else
        output = interp1(etLut, blLut, ET);
    end
 end
```

**C++**

```
void Preprocessor::CalculateBlackLevel(black_level* blackLevelDataNative, double analogGain, double exposureTime, double output[])
{
    const int NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS = 4;
    std::vector<double> exposureTimeLut;    
    std::vector<std::array<int, NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS> > blackLevelLut;

    if (blackLevelDataNative->num_bl_luts == 1 )
    {
        std::array<int, NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS> arr;
        arr[0] = blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[0]->black_level[0];
        arr[1] = blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[0]->black_level[1];
        arr[2] = blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[0]->black_level[2];
        arr[3] = blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[0]->black_level[3];
        blackLevelLut.push_back(arr);
    }       
    else           
    {
        double maxAnalogGain = blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[0]->analog_gain;
        double minAnalogGain = blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[0]->analog_gain;
        for (int num = 0; num < blackLevelDataNative->num_bl_luts; num++)
        {
            maxAnalogGain = std::max(maxAnalogGain, blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[num]->analog_gain);
            minAnalogGain = std::min(minAnalogGain, blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[num]->analog_gain);
        }
        if (analogGain >= maxAnalogGain || analogGain <= minAnalogGain)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < blackLevelDataNative->num_bl_luts; k++)
            {
                //find which points you need to interpolate
                if(analogGain >= blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[k]->analog_gain && analogGain <=blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[k+1]->analog_gain)
                {
                    std::array<int, NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS> arr;
                    for (int ch = 0; ch < NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS; ch++)
                    {
                        //y = y0 + (y1-y0)*(x-x0)/(x1-x0);
                        double y0 = blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[k]->black_level[ch];
                        double y1 = blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[k+1]->black_level[ch];
                        double x = analogGain;
                        double x0 = blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[k]->analog_gain;
                        double x1 = blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[k + 1]->analog_gain;
                        arr[ch] =  y0 + (y1-y0)*(x-x0)/(x1-x0);
                    }
                    blackLevelLut.push_back(arr);
                    //if the vector does not contains the exposure, add if to the vector
                    if (std::find(exposureTimeLut.begin(), exposureTimeLut.end(), blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[k]->exposure_time) == exposureTimeLut.end())
                    {
                        exposureTimeLut.push_back(blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[k]->exposure_time);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else //extrapolate nearest neighbor
        {            
            for (int k = 0; k < blackLevelDataNative->num_bl_luts; k++)
            {
                if (analogGain > maxAnalogGain)
                {
                    if(blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[k]->analog_gain == maxAnalogGain)
                    {
                        std::array<int, NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS> arr;
                        for (int ch = 0; ch < NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS; ch++)
                        {
                            arr[ch] =  blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[k]->black_level[ch];
                        }
                        blackLevelLut.push_back(arr);
                        //if the vector does not contains the exposure, add if to the vector
                        if (std::find(exposureTimeLut.begin(), exposureTimeLut.end(), blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[k]->exposure_time) == exposureTimeLut.end())
                        {
                            exposureTimeLut.push_back(blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[k]->exposure_time);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else //analogGain < minAnalogGain
                {
                    if(blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[k]->analog_gain == minAnalogGain)
                    {
                        std::array<int, NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS> arr;
                        for (int ch = 0; ch < NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS; ch++)
                        {
                            arr[ch] =  arr[ch] =  blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[k]->black_level[ch];
                        }
                        blackLevelLut.push_back(arr);
                        //if the vector does not contains the exposure, add if to the vector
                        if (std::find(exposureTimeLut.begin(), exposureTimeLut.end(), blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[k]->exposure_time) == exposureTimeLut.end())
                        {
                            exposureTimeLut.push_back(blackLevelDataNative->black_level_luts[k]->exposure_time);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    if(exposureTimeLut.size() == 1 )
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {

        std::vector<double>::iterator iterMax = std::max_element(exposureTimeLut.begin(), exposureTimeLut.end());
        std::vector<double>::iterator iterMin = std::min_element(exposureTimeLut.begin(), exposureTimeLut.end());

        for (int k = 0; k < exposureTimeLut.size(); k++)
        {
            if(exposureTime <= *iterMax && exposureTime >= *iterMin ) //interpolate
            {
                //find which points you need to interpolate
                if(exposureTime >= exposureTimeLut[k] && exposureTime <= exposureTimeLut[k+1])
                {
                    for (int ch = 0; ch < NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS; ch++)
                    {
                        //y = y0 + (y1-y0)*(x-x0)/(x1-x0);
                        double y0 = blackLevelLut[k][ch];
                        double y1 = blackLevelLut[k+1][ch];
                        double x = exposureTime;
                        double x0 = exposureTimeLut[k];
                        double x1 = exposureTimeLut[k +1];
                        output[ch] =  y0 + (y1-y0)*(x-x0)/(x1-x0);
                    }
                    return; //break the loop
                }             
            }
            else //extrapolate nearest neighbor
            {
                for (int ch = 0; ch < NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS; ch++)
                {
                    if(exposureTime > *iterMax )
                    {                    
                        output[ch] = blackLevelLut[exposureTimeLut.size()-1][ch];     
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        output[ch] = blackLevelLut[0][ch];
                    }                    
                }
                return;
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the code produce the correct output?

Comment: yes I have checked it for a few inputs. not all of the types